# python 3 IRC bot syntax error

Tags: python, irc, bots

Okay, first off. I'm very new to python, and I've just started to teach myself python 3 
 As a fun project to help me learn I decieded to do an IRC Bot, I figured I'll follow a basic tutorial on creating a basic bot, and as I learn I could add more to it, and make it my own but the problem is I believe
the tutorial was written for python 2.x. I've gotten a few errors that I was able to fix on my own, but now I'm getting this syntax error that I cant seem to figure out.
the error is on line 39, here are lines 38 and 39, (38 because I had a syntax error there but managed to fix it)

```
if msgpart[0]=='`' and sender[0]==OWNER  # Treat all messages start with ` as a command
   cmd=msgpart[1:].split('')
```

and the error I get is.

```
File "pybot.py", line 39
cmd=msgpart[1:].split('')
  ^
Syntax error: invalid syntax
```

the error on line 38 was kind of the same thing, but with that I removed the : after owner and it fixed
itself, which seemed weird to me because from what I understand theres supposed to be : after IF statements.

Comment: You do need a colon after `OWNER`, what exact error message were you getting? "kind of the same thing" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: I get the same invalid syntax error when the colin is after the if statement, which is why its not making sense to me.

Comment: @RobbieK: Once you've put the `:` back in, check the lines before - a `SyntaxError` can mean you've forgotten to close a bracket - ) ] or }.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `:` after `if` statement. Should be:

```
if msgpart[0]=='`' and sender[0]==OWNER:
   cmd=msgpart[1:].split('')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon `:` at the end of the `if` statement:

```
if msgpart[0]=='`' and sender[0]==OWNER  # Treat all messages start with ` as a command
                                       ^
```

should be:

```
if msgpart[0]=='`' and sender[0]==OWNER:  # Treat all messages start with ` as a command
                                       ^
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot but as I was trying to say when there is a colon at the end of that if statement I get a syntax error on that line. with the ^ under the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your tabs and spaces are consistent in the source file. There seem to be 3 spaces in front of line 39 (normally it's 4, or at least some even number).

Plus the colon `:` at line 38 like others said.

The empty string in `split('')` is no syntax error, but it also looks weird. What are you trying to achieve there?